# How to trigger the delete character in textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form with a `textarea` I submit the form after 1 second when the `textarea`'s raises a `change` (or `input` or `propertychange`) event. I'm keeping the content of `textarea` after submit. It works when I write anything in the `textarea`. But when I delete any character the submit isn't done. My markup:

```js
var timeoutId;
$('form input, form textarea').on('input propertychange change', function() {
  console.log('Textarea Change');
  //alert("chang Comment!");
  var value = editor.getValue();

  clearTimeout(timeoutId);
  timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {

    document.forms["preview-form"].submit();
  }, 1000);
});

$('.contact-form').submit(function(e) {
  saveToDB();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form class="contact-form" id="preview-form" action="textAreaData" method="post">
  <textarea id="preview-form-comment" name="preview-form-comment">${data}</textarea>
  <input type="submit" name="preview-form=submit" id="preview-form-submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

What must I do to submit when I delete a character in the `textarea`?

Comment: [Works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/gb1t2xtg/) if I make a couple of reasonable assumptions.

Comment: Beware, though, that `document.forms["preview-form"].submit();` will actually submit the form and will not trigger your `submit` handler (because you're calling `HTMLFormElement#submit` directly).

Comment: Finally: This has nothing to do with JSP, I've removed the [tag:jsp] tag for you and cleaned up the text.

Comment: if I remove (document.forms["preview-form"].submit();) then the submit not run after x second .... so what I can do to solve problem ? @T.J. Crowder

Comment: what I can replace (document.forms["preview-form"].submit();)  to trigger delete any character  handler ?

Answer (score 2):

thanks for all ... My problem was  because I use codemirror ... so I must to write :

```
editor.on('change', function() {}
```